# Draw 60 000 circles UWP

Tags: animation, uwp, draw, win2d

I need to draw 60 times per second 60 000 little circles in different positions. What's the fastest way to do it? 
Win2d fillcircle and spritebatch are not fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Win2D is managed layer on top of DirectX. If you need to get closer to the metal than that, you'll have to use DirectX directly. You can get an overview of DirectX on UWP [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/index).